# getting results based on a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch data from my DB based on the value in my pivot table.

These are my tables:

```
uploads
-> id
-> name
-> type

emails
-> id
-> email


upload_emails
-> id
-> upload_id
-> email_id
-> url
```

Now for example I have the following url: `1234`

How can I select the upload that is attached to the pivot table `'upload_email'`
where the url value in the pivot table matches `1234`

I had the following

```
Upload::emails()->wherePivot('url', $key)->get();
```

But that's not working at all. I do have the relations set up in my model etc...

EDIT:

After the suggested answer I'm pretty close. This is what I have now:

```
return Upload::with(array('emails' => function($query) use ($key) {
    $query->wherePivot('url', $key);
}))->get();
```

I have 9 uploads in my database. When I use the query above, it returns all uploads, but the emails are only included on the matching pivot url. But that's not what I want, I only want 1 upload. The one where the pivot url matches my value.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a Many to Many relationship?

Comment: It is set up as a many to many relationship.

Comment: also where did you get the `url`?

Comment: i edited my initial post, the key field is actually the url, no idea where my head was when writing the initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your tables all you need is to fix this:

```
Upload::emails()->wherePivot('url', $key)->get(); // no url field on that table!
// change to:
Upload::find($id)->emails()->wherePivot('key', $key)->get();
// or if you want a collection then:
Upload::with(array('emails'=> function ($q) use ($key) {
   $qwherePivot('key', $key);
}))->get();

// to fetch only those Upload models that have related email matching given 'key'
Upload::whereHas('emails', function ($q) use ($key) {
   $q->where('upload_emails.key', $key);
})->get(); // add the above with(...) method to also load those emails
```

Comment: The last example works pretty well, except its giving my all the existing uploads, bu only includes the email on the matching url. What i want is to only get the upload that matches the pivot url

Comment: Edited my answer then. wherePivot() doesn't work in whereHas, so you need to excplicitly name the field.

Answer (score 0):

Eager loading constraints using the `with` method could be what you need:

```
Upload::with('email', function($q) use($key) {
  $q->where('url', $key);
})->get();
```

check [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$upload = Upload::with(array('email' => function($query) use ($key) {
   // where is URL in the table? shouldn't it be 'key'?
   $query->where('key', $key); 
}))->get();
```

---

**notes**

As `wherePivot` and `orWherePivot` has become available, see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L76-L103).

You have to add the additional column to your relationship like this:

```
public function emails(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot("key");
}
```

Supposedly with Laravel 4.1 you can add another method to your model:

```
$upload = Upload::emails()->wherePivot('key', $key)->get();
```